# How do I send an email from Unity WebGL

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm currently working on a configurator project for Unity and I have hit a bit of a snag. I currently have it hosted on my website with WebGL.

What I'm wanting to do is to take the users selection and have it sent out via email so we can see what the user selected.

I haven't had any luck finding a solution for this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've been attempting to write a php script that might be able to take information directly from unity on the webpage and send it out. But I haven't had any luck figuring out how to get it to work.

Comment: What email account do you want to use to send the emails?

Comment: sending data from unity to php is well documented, and does make sense that you would trigger an ability to try send the email from the server side.  If your webhoster provides an email service you can use, you can use that, or you can try use smtp services of gmail etc, which is also documented.  Please be more specific with your exact issue.

Comment: [`SmtpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient) (just have in mind hat async stuff might not work in WebGL so you should stick to the sync methods)

Comment: @BugFinder I just don't know how to do it, and I haven't really found any documentation on how to go about it. Could you provide links to the documentation so I can look into it?

I have a gmail account set-up to send the emails out but from what I can find it might not be supported?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly! Here's a brief explanation of how you can send an email from inside Unity using C#:

1. Import the necessary namespaces:

   - `System.Net.Mail`: This namespace provides classes for sending emails using the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP).
2. Create an instance of the `MailMessage` class:

   - Set the sender's email address (`From` property).
   - Add the recipient's email address (`To` property).
   - Set the subject of the email (`Subject` property).
   - Set the body of the email (`Body` property).
3. Create an instance of the `SmtpClient` class:

   - Specify the SMTP server to be used (e.g., `"smtp.gmail.com"`).
   - Set the port number for the SMTP server (usually `587` for TLS encryption).
   - Provide the sender's email address and password for authentication (`Credentials` property).
   - Enable SSL/TLS encryption (`EnableSsl` property).
4. Send the email using the `Send` method of the `SmtpClient` class:

   - Pass the `MailMessage` object as an argument to the `Send` method.
5. Handle any necessary exceptions that may occur during the email sending process.

Remember to replace the placeholder values (`senderEmail`, `senderPassword`, `recipientEmail`, `subject`) with your actual email addresses and desired subject lines.

By following these steps, you can send emails from within your Unity project using C#.

Comment: you can use PHP also to do that, if you need help regarding that I can provide Help

Comment: Thank you for the help. I don't believe this method is supported in WebGL from what I can find. But I would absolutely love some assistance with the PHP method.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer?